# Winforms DevExpress UnitOfWork - Check if the values to save from UnitOfWork aren't already in the database

Tags: winforms, devexpress

In an application we inherited (Winforms) based on DevExpress, an object of type UnitOfWork is used to keep track and save multiples records in the database.
Usually around 100 objects can be saved in the database on a button click using the method    UnitOfWork.CommitChanges();
The table where the records are inserted has an unique constraint on a column.
It might happen that different users try to treat the same entities and to try to enter in that table the same value in the unique column.
So definitively before using UnitOfWork.CommitChanges() we should test if one or more values do not exist already in the database. 
What would be the best approach to test if one or more objects  are not already in the database before calling UnitOfWork.CommitChanges(), so that we can surely warn the user on his validation?

Thank you

Comment: Please show us what you've already done to accomplish this.

Comment: I tried to see if the objects exist already in the database by loading a collection with a filter , but definiteveley it is not the way to go:  XPCollection<TableauDeclarationSeances> seancesDB = new XPCollection<TableauDeclarationSeances>(UnitOfWork);
                             CriteriaOperator filter = CriteriaOperator.Parse("fSeanceId in (" + str.ToString() + ")");
                              seancesDB.Filter = filter;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really the DevExpress way of working, see the help topic on [auto-generated keys](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/DevExpressXpoKeyAttribute_AutoGeneratetopic).

However, since you have inherited the code, you could use *[UnitOfWork.GetObjectsToSave()](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/DevExpressXpoSession_GetObjectsToSavetopic)* to obtain an *ICollection* of the *IXPObjects* you are about to commit. From this collection you could generate a list of potential key conflicts. Then you could use *[UnitOfWork.ExecuteScalar()](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/DevExpressXpoSession_ExecuteScalartopic)* to run a direct SQL command to determine if there are conflicts and resolve them.

The [UnitOfWork.CommitChanges()](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/DevExpressXpoUnitOfWork_CommitChangestopic) calls CommitTransaction, so you could perform this check in one of the UnitOfWork events such as [UnitOfWork.BeforeCommitTransaction](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/DevExpressXpoSession_BeforeCommitTransactiontopic).

As with everything DevExpress, your best support option is the [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you ask for is not possible to implement in a multiuser system. As every user (necessarily) works in his own database transaction, there is always a chance for a user to insert a datarow with a key that another user inserted right before. You could only avoid this by employing database mechanisms like autogenerated keys. But I think this is not applicable for you.

So I suggest to catch the exception thrown by commitChanges and act upon it.

Comment: Thanks.. I do agree. I probably can display a message to the user when an error occurs and try to discard the changes made on the UnitOfWork..